# How to create custom draggable widget in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, dashboard, meta-boxes, custom-widgets

i need to make some blocks(widgets) like the same of WordPress dashboard widgets. that means if we dragged a widget to another position it wouldn't change after refreshing the page. is there any way for the same.?? i want some blocks or widgets (functioning like dashboard widgets) in my custom plugin. :)

Comment: Take a moment to familiarize yourself with the platform and how to ask questions. Tip: google "custom draggable widgets wordpress"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this:

```
function your_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Theme Support', 'your_widget_callback');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'your_dashboard_widgets');

function your_widget_callback() {
    echo '<p>Welcome!</p>';
}
```

Comment: Doing this will add the widgets to the admin dashboard area. Is it possible to add the widgets to a specific page in a plugin?